# Weird C-N bond in caffeine

Tags: bond, molecular-structure

I saw this picture on a teacher's wall and I noticed the C single bonded to the N on the right side. How is it possible that carbon has four bonding sites but is only using one in the picture? Is this stable?

[image: structure of caffeine]

Comment: That's impossible, of course. It is just another $\ce{CH3}$ that did not fit.

Comment: Compare to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caffeine): it should be a CH₃. Also, the five-member (imidazole) ring is missing a double bond. In addition to being badly drawn.

Comment: Fun fact: The pentagon that is drawn (regardless of whether we consider it poorly drawn) tessellates unlike a 'well-drawn' imidazole ring.